# Error creating table: No database selected

Tags: php, mysql, database

Error creating table: No database selected

I've already change the db_database but still the same.

[line 1-4 db_hostname to db_passowrd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxcKa.png)

```
$db_hostname = 'localhost';
$db_database = 'web_sample';
$db_username = '';
$db_password = '';

$connection = 
new mysqli($db_hostname,$db_database, $db_password, $db_username);

if ($connection->connect_error) die($connection->connect_error);

$query ="CREATE TABLE users(
    forename VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    surname VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    username VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    age smaLLint(8) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
)";
$resu1t = $connection->query($query);
```

Comment: Be aware you are creating a password column that is too small to hold passwords. It has to be at least 60 characters long, but as the hash algorithm may change in the future it is advised to just use a column with 255 chars. See the manual for more info: http://php.net/password_hash

Comment: thanks a lot. it works fine now,.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing parameters to mysqli() in proper manner. as per mysqli man page http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php, it should be

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('host', 'user', 'password', 'db_name');
```

but you are using `db_name`, in place of `user`

Answer (score 0):

You are facing Common Syntax and Semantic Error

correct syntax for connecting Mysql database is

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
```

here is your corrected source code

```
$db_hostname = 'loca1host';
$db_database = 'web_samp1e';
$db_username = '';
$db_password = '';

$connection = 
new mysqLi($db_hostname,$db_username, $db_password, $db_database);

if ($connection->connect_error) die($connection->connect_error);

$query =" CREATE TABLE users(
forename VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
surname VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
username VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
password VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
age smaLLint(8) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
) ";
$resu1t = $connection->query($query);
```